# Whats the best way to invoke a method by Reflection in GWT

Tags: gwt, reflection

What’s the best way to invoke a method by reflection using GWT, I know that there are some frameworks like "GWT Reflection" but I really want to hear some feedback about this.
How is the best way to convert something like this:

```
GreetingServiceAsync service = GWT.create(GreetingService.class);
AsyncCallback callBack = new AsyncCallback< Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {               
            }
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void result) {            
            }
        };      
service.doSomething(callBack);

in:
GreetingServiceAsync greetingService = GWT.create(GreetingService.class);

String methodName = “doSomething”;
Object service;
AsyncCallback callBack = new AsyncCallback< Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {               
            }
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void result) {            
            }
        };

/*somehow invoke by reflection*/
Class<?> c = Class.forName(GreetingServiceAsync.class.getName());
Method  method = c.getMethod(methodName, AsyncCallback.class);
method.invoke (service, callBack);
```

Many thanks,
Luis.

Comment: Please post an update whether you were able to solve the problem. It is a nice practice to close the question if it gets solved either by choosing an answer or by posting your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript 101 - there is no concept of reflection. GWT java translates to javascript.  So gwt does not provide reflection support. Every other library that states gwt reflection in their homepage are just addressing a corner functionality and mis-stating their feature.